# Undefined function while clearly defined in ES6 class

Tags: javascript, function, class, ecmascript-6

For a new project I'm trying out the ES6 classes. However, I get the following error:

```
main.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: $container.setBackgroundColor is not a function
```

That seems weird to me as the class that $container is referring to, clearly contains the function setBackgroundColor. I also get that error with other functions in the class.

**Main javascript code**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var $container = new View("container");

    $container.setBackgroundColor("#E9425B");

    document.body.append($container);
};
```

**View Class**

```
class View{
    constructor(id){
        this.id = id;
        this.view = document.createElement(this.id);
        return this.view;
    };

    get(){
        return document.getElementsByTagName(this.id);
    };

    setText(text){
        this.get().innerText = text;
    };

    setBackgroundColor(color){
        this.get().style.backgroundColor = color;
    };

    create(id){
        if(id != null){
            this.id = id;
        }
    };

    addChild(child){
        console.log(child);
        this.get().append(child);
    };
}
```

I've done some searching, and when outputing a function of the View class to the debugging console it gives me an error that suggests the Intermediate value is not a function. After some quick research most answers state there must be a missing semicolon. I hope there's a fix for my problem.

Thanks in advance,

Pascal

Comment: Why are you returning from the constructor?

Comment: Do not put semi-colons at the end of the method declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `return this.view;` is returning the *created element*, not the class instantiation, so it has no access to the class methods. Remove the return statement so the instantiation itself is returned, and change to `.append($container);` to `.append($container.view);`.

Also, by saving the reference to the element in the `.view` property, you can get it again simply by referencing the `.view` property again - your current `get() { return document.getElementsByTagName(this.id);` won't work because the `id` isn't a tag name.

```js
class View {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.view = document.createElement(this.id);
  }

  get() {
    return this.view;
  }

  setText(text) {
    this.get().innerText = text;
  }

  setBackgroundColor(color) {
    this.get().style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

  create(id) {
    if (id != null) {
      this.id = id;
    }
  }

  addChild(child) {
    console.log(child);
    this.get().append(child);
  }
}

var $container = new View("container");
$container.setBackgroundColor("#E9425B");
$container.setText('container text');
document.body.append($container.view);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove return this.view; from constructor